# How to redirect www.blog.domain.com to another blog.domain.com using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am not sure whether it is technically correct or not. But we have to make it possible. Kindly give solution for the same.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do a permanent redirect you can use 301 redirection
put this to your .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 / http://blog.domain.com/
```

For more info refer : [enter link description here](http://allhtaccess.info)